# Arduino + Raspy3 serial problems

Tags: python, arduino, raspberry-pi

I am new to python, and I'm trying to connect an `Arduino` Uno with a Raspberry Pi3 using python. Arduino sends data (ID, Temp and Humidity) every 1 second.

The problem is that I want `raspberry` to read serial port every 5 seconds and raspy is losing data... it only gets IDs: 2,4,6,8,etc, so I'm losing data, and I also discovered that when raspy reads, it doesn't get the latest data, it seems that it's reading a buffer of the serial data(I also tried reading every second and the problem was the same).

Below is part of the code:

```python
import numpy
import sys
import time
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import pyqtSignal as Signal
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import serial

class Ventana(QMainWindow, ui_SQL.Ui_Ventana):

port1 = serial.Serial(3)   # port1 = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0')             
port1.baudrate = 9600
port1.timeout = 1

    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        self.l1 = []
        self.l2 = []
        self.l3 = []
        super(Ventana, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.cajita.clicked.connect(self.cancel1)
        timer = QTimer(self)
        timer.timeout.connect(self.medir)
        timer.start(5000)

    def medir(self):

        texto = self.port1.readline()
        texto1 = texto.split(" ")
        num1 = int(texto1[0])
        num2 = float(texto1[1])
        num3 = float(texto1[2])
        self.lect1.setText(str(num2))
        self.lect2.setText(str(num3))
        dato1 = round(num2/num3, 2)
        num4 = self.blancoSpin.value()
        dato2 = round(num4/num3, 2)
        self.muestraDo.setText(str(dato1))
        self.guardarTxt()

    def guardarTxt(self):
        guardar = self.port1.readline()
        if self.cajita.isChecked(): 
                with open(self.lineEdit.text()+'.txt', 'a') as yourFile:
                    yourFile.write("%s\n" % guardar)
```

This is the arduino code. It just sends random values.

```
int n=1;
float a;
float b;

void setup(){

Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
a = random(10, 30000);
a /= 100;
b = random(900,1100);
b /= 100;
Serial.print(n);
Serial.print(" ");
Serial.print(a);
Serial.print(" ");
Serial.println(b);
n +=1;
delay(1000);
}
```

Could someone please help me?

Comment: What's your Arduino code? Have you already tried to put a `Serial.flush()` in the Arduino sketch to see if it helps?

Comment: sorry for that, I forget to add the arduino code...I will update the post

Comment: As I said, try to put a `Serial.flush();` right before the `n += 1;`, and see if that helps, maybe it's just a matter of buffering.

Comment: @ChatterOne, i´ve tried the serial.flush() but it doesn´t work. Keep losing point...i get one...i lost one...doesn´t matter if I change the delay() on `arduino`, I tried using dalay(2000), delay(10000) and also the same numbers on `raspberry`, but keep missing data

Comment: If `Serial.flush()` didn't work, try to break it into small problems. Run only the Arduino code and see what you get on the serial monitor. What happens if you send a single string, like "abcdefgh1234567890", to the Raspberry? Also, you may want to have a look at this thread: http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=224241

Comment: @ChatterOne, I tried breaking it, and I realize that maybe the problem is when `python` opens the txt in order to read it, it seems that all the program stops and somehow it loses the following data package. When I remove the `guardarTxt` (wich means saveTxt), the script works perfect (I added a line in order to show the results in a label). Now I´m trying with threading...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those having the same problem, I finally solved this issue using Threading....here I paste part of the modified code:

```
class guardarTxt (QtCore.QThread):

    def __init__(self, texto, nombre):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.texto = texto

    def __del__(self):
        self.wait()

    def run (self):
        with open(nombre+'.txt', 'a') as yourFile:
            yourFile.write("%s\n" % texto)
        self.terminate()
```

And, in `class Ventana`, i´ve changed `self.guardarTxt()` for the following:

```
nombre = self.lineEdit.text()
self.guardarTxt = guardarTxt(texto, nombre)
self.guardarTxt.start()
```